# PHP Regex to match the last occurrence of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

My string is `$text1 = 'A373R12345'` 
I want to find last none digital number occurrence of this string.
So I use this regular expression `^(.*)[^0-9]([^-]*)`
Then I got this result:
1.A373
2.12345

But my expected result is:
1.A373R
 
(It has 'R')
2.12345

Another example is `$text1 = 'A373R+12345'`
Then I got this result:
1.A373R
2.12345

But my expected result is:
1.A373R+
 
(It has '+')
2.12345

I want contain the last none digital number!!
Please help !! thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$text1 = 'A373R12345';
preg_match('/^(.*[^\d])(\d+)$/', $text1, $match);
echo $match[1]; // A373R
echo $match[2]; // 12345

$text1 = 'A373R+12345';
preg_match('/^(.*[^\d])(\d+)$/', $text1, $match);
echo $match[1]; // A373R+
echo $match[2]; // 12345
```

Explanation of regex broken down:

```
^ match from start of string
(.*[^\d]) match any amount of characters where the last character is not a digit 
(\d+)$ match any digit character until end of string
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine for my situtaion!! thanks!!
Could you explain the regular expression for me? I only know.*[^\d] mean you wan to find the last none digital number

Comment: @crypticツ What tool do you have used?