# Finding the last occurrence of href

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a link using regexp which appears just before textABCXYZ123 string in below HTML .

```
lorem ispum...<strong><a href="http://www.site.com/link/123">FIRSTlink</a> </strong><br>
1 points| Saved Jan 08, 2014 at 00:49 <span class=notes_box>ANOTHERLINK</span>.
... more text........... more text........
... more text.......<strong><a href="http://www.site.com/link/123">other link</a> </strong><br>
1 points| Saved Jan 08, 2014 at 00:49 <span class=notes_box>ANOTHERLINK</span>.
... more text........... more text........
<strong><a href="http://www.IneedThis.com/link/123">somewhere to go</a> </strong><br>
1 points| Saved Jan 08, 2014 at 00:49 <span class=notes_box>textABCXYZ123</span>
...
... more text..........<strong><a href="http://www.site.com/link/123">other link</a> </strong><br>
1 points| Saved Jan 08, 2014 at 00:49 <span class=notes_box>ANOTHERLINK</span>.
... more text........... more text........
```

There are many links and I need to capture the link which appears just before textABCXYZ123 string. i tried below regex but it is returning me first link instead of last one:

```
$find_string = 'ABCXYZ123';
preg_match('#href="(.*)".*text'.$find_string.'#sU',$html,$match);
// so final resutl is "http://www.site.com/link/123" which is first link
```

Can someone guide me how can I capture that link just before my string textABCXYZ123? P.S I know about xpath and simple html dom but I would like to match with regexp. Thanks for any input.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618077/php-regex-to-match-the-last-occurrence-of-a-string for finding the last occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe try the regex:

```
href="([^"]*)">(?=(?:(?!href).)*textABCXYZ123)
```

Like so?

```
$find_string = 'ABCXYZ123';
preg_match('~href="([^"]*)">(?=(?:(?!href).)*text'.$find_string.')~sU',$html,$match);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kU3wN6)

---

The first part is `href="([^"]*)">` and shouldn't be too hard to understand. It matches `href="` and then any number of non-quote characters, followed by quotes and `>`.

`(?=(?:(?!href).)*textABCXYZ123)` first is a positive lookahead. (A positive lookahead has the format `(?= ... )`) It will make sure that there is what's inside to say that there is a match.

For instance, `a(?=.*b)` matches any `a`, as long as there is any characters, then a `b` somewhere after the `a` (also means it matches `a` as long as there's a `b` somewhere after it).

So, `href="([^"]*)">` will match only if there is `(?:(?!href).)*textABCXYZ123` somewhere ahead.

`(?:(?!href).)*` is a modified `.*`, because the negative lookahead (format `(?! ... )`) makes sure no `href` is matched. You could say it's the opposite of a positive lookahead:

`a(?!.*b)` matches any `a` as long as it is *not* followed by a `b`.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly how I wanted, Could you please explain a bit your pattern. I am very novice to regex and it will be a big help to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: @user969068 Added some more explanation. Hopefully, that's not too difficult to understand :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. Much useful. Cant thank enough...Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
(?s)href=[^<]+</a>(?!.*(href).*(textABCXYZ123))(?=.*(textABCXYZ123))
```

Could also try this, let me know if you want an explantation